# Excel file to mysql

Tags: mysql, database, excel

I am creating a web application to collect some specific data from users. What I want is that the user uploads an excel file containing the data on the web page I created and that excel file stores its data on MySQL database.
Is it possible?How?

Comment: Do you run your web service on your own server enviroment so that you can run cron jobs?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible.

I would convert the Excel file to a csv file, or make the user upload a csv file instead. Excel already has this feature build in.

Then in MySQL you can turn the csv file into a tmp table with ease:

```
LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\nameoffile.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE `tmp_table` CHARACTER SET latin1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

After that you transfer your data from the tmp table into the tables you'd like and finally you delete the temporary table.

Comment: Wouldn't CSV be `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','`? :0)

Comment: Yeah, they normally would. I just happened to have a CSV file with another seperator.

Comment: If you like my answer please tick it of as the right answer. Otherwise I'm willing to go into more detail and help you out.